# Book (possibly the first one in a series) with psychic runaway kids living in a prop warehouse that has a dragon

Tags: story-identification, novel, psychic

I remember getting this as a paperback from the Dollar Tree, I think in the late 1990s or early 2000s, in Kentucky. The protagonists are a group of kids (I think a mix of teenagers and prepubescents, also a mix of genders) who have psychic powers, at the least telekinesis. There may have been an unrelated male adult caretaker who was watching over them. I think they were on the run to avoid being scooped up by the government. They were squatting in a warehouse that contained movie props (which does suggest Los Angeles as a setting), including a massive dragon that, at some point, they use their powers to animate to drive off some intruders. Unfortunately, most of the rest of the details are escaping me. I think it was a fairly slim paperback, between 100-200 pages, and that the cover was black, with images of the children around a central image of the dragon. It was written in English, and I think was billed as the first book in a series. I want to say that, at least on the cover, the children were all caucasian, although I don't remember any hair or eye colors.